# コサイン類似度結果が思った通りの結果と違う理由はなぜでしょうか?

Tags: javascript, アルゴリズム

プログラミング初心者です。

コサイン類似度を勉強している際、入力したデータが明らかに違うのにも関わらず、結果値が高い値を示します。

AとBの比較では0.89という妥当な値が出ますが、AとDはデータの内容が明らかに違うにも関わらず0.9という結果が出ます。

これはなぜなのでしょうか?

言語はjavascriptです。

```
let A = [20,60,80];
let B = [20,80,40];
let C = [70,20,70];
let D = [1,1,1];

cos(A,B);
cos(A,C);
cos(A,D);

function cos(val1,val2) {
    //初期化
    let A1 = 0;
    let B1 = 0;
    let ab1 = 0;
    let ab2 = 0;
    let ab3 = 0;
    let cosθ = 0;
    
    //データ入力
    A1 = val1;
    B1 = val2;
    
    //事前計算
    for (let i = 0; i < A1.length; i++) {
        ab1 += A1[i] * B1[i];
        ab2 += A1[i] * A1[i];
        ab3 += B1[i] * B1[i];
    }

    //コサイン類似度のアルゴリズム
    cosθ =  ab1 / (Math.sqrt(ab2)*Math.sqrt(ab3));
    
    //計算結果
    console.log(cosθ);
}
```

cos(A,B); →　0.8987170342729172
cos(A,C); →　0.7961540283151327
cos(A,D); →　0.9058216273156766

Comment: 別の言語等でも結果は一緒なので、今回の問題は言語やアルゴリズムの問題ではなくて、直感的にはAとDが最も類似度が低いと思われるのに数学的にAとDのほうが高いのはなぜ？ということですかね？

Comment: そうです。質問の仕方が下手くそですいません。なぜこのような結果になるのかわかりません。解説が頂けると助かります。

Comment: ちなみにベクトルはわかりますか？

Comment: すいません。理解しておりません....。基礎的な部分から勉強し直します...。

Answer (score 2):

コサイン類似度=ベクトルの**向き**の似ている度合い、だそうなので、大きさをそろえると

```
A = [1,3,4];
B = [1,4,2];

D = [1,1,1]; [2,2,2]でも [4,4,4]でも
```

となり、A,BとA,Dで明らかに違う数値になるはず、にはならないと思います。